# Can the vacation e-mail auto-responder cope with Berkeley DB version skew?

Tags: email, database, compatibility

We have a typical account domain with NFS home directories, accessible by the mail server as well as various user workstations.

Do the versions of the `vacation` package installed on the mail server and the workstations need to match?

My understanding is that the `vacation` program uses a Berkeley DB to keep track of which senders it has already auto-replied to, so as not to send bounce messages to the same sender twice.  What if the database is created on a workstation whose `vacation` is linked to one version of Berkeley DB, and subsequently used by the MDA, where the `vacation` on the mail server is linked to some other version of Berkeley DB?  Will that cause a failure?

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/upgrade_process.html),

> Berkeley DB major and minor releases may optionally include changes in all four areas, that is, the application API, region files, database formats, and log files may not be backward-compatible with previous releases.

So I'm worried that letting different versions of the Berkeley DB library access the same `~/.vacation.{db,dir,pag}` files could cause data corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `vacation` does use Berkeley DB for the purpose you described.

Indeed, you *could* run into problems if you try and access the same Berkeley DB files using different versions of the client libraries. The on-disk format does change from time to time and upgrading is normally handled transparently by the client application (or manually, using the `db_upgrade` script). Once the database files have been upgraded, there's no guarantee that a client using a previous version of the client libraries will be able to access the database files that have been upgraded. In light of that, it's probably a prudent step to synchronise the `vacation` versions across your estate just to be safe.

There's another issue (although it's probably minor) - you can run into concurrent access problems accessing Berkeley DB over NFS. See the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html#CanBerkeleyDBuseNFSSANorotherremotesharednetworkfilesystemsfordatabasesandtheirenvironments) for more information. I'd imagine it's probably not a big problem though, as `vacation` isn't a transaction processing system.